# vuejs - show alert and redirect after submiting axios form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

i have a form which is working fine and inserting data but if the user press the submit button 10 times it insert the data 10 times so i want to redirect the user to another page and show him the success message or error . here i am using axios as below i have added the then resoponse and catch error but its not displaying i think i have to show in html some how:

```
reserve() {
            // this.form.post('../api/comment')
            axios.post('../api/reserve',{
                property_id:1,
                reserve_start:this.date,
                reserve_end:this.date2,
            }).then(response => {
                self.message = 'Data is entered'
            })
                .catch(error => {
                    self.message = 'Error'
                })
```

and here is my form markup :

```
 <form @submit.prevent="reserve()"  id="myForm"  class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right m-form--group-seperator-dashed">
```

Comment: One other possible solution is: Once your request is either successful or decline, then reset your form input inside your `.then` and `.catch` part. Hence doing so you can make sure you don't pass same instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward to redirect in a method after an axios call.

something like this:

```
reserve() {
// this.form.post('../api/comment')
  axios.post('../api/reserve',{
    property_id:1,
    reserve_start:this.date,
    reserve_end:this.date2,
  }).then(response => {
    this.$router.push('/routeToGoTo')      
  })
}
.catch(error => {
  self.message = 'Error'
})
```

You could put an alert before the router.push and this will stop everything until it is dimissed. So the alert would show, user clicks ok, page redirects.

`alert("Something was done.")`

Comment: i dont know why but this is not working it just returning backto the same page with no mesage but still inserts

Comment: @Farshad, what router are you putting in the `this.$router.push('/routeToGoTo')`?